# Dwarf corpse not being moved

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have a dwarf who died of thirst in my jewellers. He's been there for, like half a year now. He's a skeleton now. No one has gone in to the workshop despite there being lots of jobs assigned there, no one will move the body. I tried telling them to dump it, but no one went near it. Why hasn't anyone moved the body? Someone else has since died of thirst and been moved to my graveyard, so I know it's not just that I don't have anyone with burial assigned.

What are my options? I want my jewellers back...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dwarf Fortress corpses](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1867/dwarf-fortress-corpses)

Comment: (1) Why would you vote to close an alreaady answered question? (2) The accepted answer on the linked question was "wait a bit, they'll get round to it" which clearly didn't work, as was made clear in the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chances are very good that you built the jeweler's workshop in such a way as to block the only exit. This is very common with the jeweler's workshop because (I think) it's the only workshop that blocks one entire side of the 3x3 grid (the right or east side). When you build the workshop, the darker X's show you which tiles will become impassible. If this is the case, deconstruct the workshop and build it elsewhere.

Otherwise check for forbidden doors or defined burrows that don't allow access.

Comment: I removed and rebuilt the room.That worked.

Answer (score 1):

Is anyone assigned the hauling labours in a burrow that can access that area? Dwarves won't do jobs outside their burrows.